# is my proof regarding the Zeros of polynomial over an infinite field correct?

Tags: solution-verification, field-theory

i want to prove that if $K$ is an infinite field and  $f\in K[X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n]$ is a nonzero polynomial, then

> There exists $c_1,c_2,\cdots,c_n\in K $ such that $f(c_1,c_2,\cdots,c_n)\neq 0$.

i wanted to prove this theorem by contradiction can you evaluate the following proof to see if it is correct or not?

*proof*: suppose that for all $c_1,c_2,\cdots,c_n\in K $ we have that  $f(c_1,c_2,\cdots,c_n) = 0$. then since field must have Identity element we have $1\in K $ then for all $c_1 $ we have  $f(c_1,1,\cdots,1) = 0 $ then it implies that for all

$f(c_1,1,\cdots,1) = $
$ \sum a_{i_1,\cdots, i_n} $
$ c_1^ {i_ {1}} $ $ \cdots $ $ c_n^ {i} $ =
$ \sum a_{i_1,\cdots, i_n} $
$ c_1^ {i_ {1}} $ $ \cdots $ $ 1^ {i} $
= $ \sum a_{i_1,\cdots, i_n} $
$ c_1^ {i_ {1}} $ $ = 0 $

which implies that $ c_1 = 0 $ if we let that one coefficient be equal to 1 and all other coefficients be set to 0.because $c_1$ is a evaluation of a non zero polynomial. then for all of $c_1$ which belong to our field K we showed that $ c_1 = 0 $  hence we have a finite field hence we get a contradiction so our prior proposition must be true.

is this proof correct?

Comment: sorry i meant the coefficients, edited it.

Comment: but still since the said above polynomial is a non zero one, we can induce that all of the elements of our field are zero hence they are finite is the conclusion wrong?

Comment: that's easy just take one coefficient in polynomial where there is  c_1^1  to be equal to one and set all other coefficients to be zero

Comment: well it would not matter because i just want to get a contradiction by stating that our field would be finite by our assumption all the polynomials would be zero

Comment: well my proof is not complete because it does not prove the result for every polynomial i guess

Comment: but i guess the result would is correct for the polynomials where there c1^1

Comment: is there any other way than unique factorization to prove the result?